# What seals would suit my Torterra?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

I want to get seals for my Torterra but i have been unable to find some that suit him. I am looking for brown or green colour effects to suit his type and colour. I would like to know if there are any seals to suit my Torterra and how to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately green is not a common colour among seals. According to [Bulbapedia's list of seals](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Seal):

- Ele-Seals B and D fire green lightning bolts.
- Party Seal C creates green confetti.
- Song Seal A makes a green treble clef.
- The D, L, and T letter seals are green.

There are no brown seals whatsoever.